# Jquery: selecting grand grand parents by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select an element by clicking on its grand grand grand child. But I can't find the way without using `parent().parent()` etc.

**General HTML**

I have an HTML divided in pages

```
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
<div class="page"></div>
```

**Inner page HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="">
        <div class="to_move">
            <div class="">
                <div class="clicked_element"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When clicking `clicked_element` I want to copy `to_move` class element to previous `page`.

The inner structure of the `page` element is not always the same, that's why I want to avoid using multiple `parent()`.

**I tried**

```
$(this).parentsUntil('.page').html()
```

But I get only `clicked_element` parent.

```
$(this).parents('.page').html()
```

With this `parents()` option I get `undefined`.

```
$(this).closest('.page').html()
```

Again I get `undefined`.

Any clues welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with `parent().parent()`? If you're sure of the children, this is a valid way.

Comment: The inner structure of the page is not always the same. That's why I want to avoid multiple 'parents()'

Comment: Please show the code in which you are running the statements you have tried. Whether they work or not depends on what `this` is at the time of execution.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log($(this).is(".clicked_element"))`?  Or even just `console.log(this)`?  Is it `undefined`?  What *exactly* is `this` in your context?  Many of your examples would work, but not if `this` is not correct - how are you defining your `click` event?  `$(".clicked_element").click(() => { ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could very well use `closest` :

```js
$('body').on('click', '.clicked_element', function() {
  $(this).closest('.page').clone().appendTo('body')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="">
    <div class="to_move">
      <div class="">
        <div class="clicked_element">Click me to copy my whole class</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP mentions an attempt to use `closest` fails...

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parents('.page')` should work. I'm guessing you're binding the the wrong event. The key to this answer is not the selector (`$(this).parents`...) but the event binding (`$(".clicked_element").click`...). In your case, I guess that `this` is not the element you were looking for because the event binding is probably wrong.

```js
$(".clicked_element").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parents('.page').attr('printme'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page" printme="You found me!">
    <div class="">
        <div class="to_move">
            <div class="">
                <div class="clicked_element" style="width: 250px; height:250px; background-color: blue">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```